pam_prompt() Giving Conversation failed RHEL 9.4 when used with SSH
I have build a custom pam module to add MFA.
After entering password I have used pam_prompt() function to display options for MFA and take user input.
That pam_prompt() is returning code 19 (PAM_CONV_ERR) "Conversation Failed" with SSH.
Same function when used by UI to Display MFA list is working fine.
Any idea of it.
Same is working on RHEL 8. I am currently using RHEL 9.4
Code where I am sing pam_prompt function
int pam_result = pam_prompt(pamh, PAM_PROMPT_ECHO_ON, &p, "%s", prompt);
if (pam_result != PAM_SUCCESS) {
    sprintf(msg, "[ERROR] pam_prompt failed with code: %d", pam_result);
    debug(pamh, msg);
    return pam_result;
}

my sshd file on test machine
#%PAM-1.0
auth       substack     password-auth
auth       include      postlogin
account    required     pam_sepermit.so
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      password-auth
password   include      password-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open env_params
session    required     pam_namespace.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    optional     pam_motd.so
session    include      password-auth
session    include      postlogin
auth       required     pam_otp.so config=/etc/pam_otp.conf use_first_pass

Usecase:
After installing my custom pam module by adding it at the end of sshd file
"auth required pam_otp.sp".
When I take ssh using
"ssh username@ip" it prompts for password.
After entering the password control goes to my pam module for MFA. Now next it should show the list of MFA options available. For that I have used the above code that has pam_prompt() function.
That is giving above mentioned error.
This problem has arrived only with RHEL 9. Till 8 its working fine
